# Eclipse Project ORA-28040 Exception Despite Updated OJDBC

Tags: java, oracle, eclipse, jdb

I joined a new project and I am working on it through Eclipse. For reference, the server is running on Oracle 19c, and is being managed by a different team.

I tried putting the project onto my Tomcat server and connecting to it, but it gives me an ORA-28040 exception. Here's the exact exception message:

```
2022/1/11 11:08:45.847  [TRACE] com.nuorbit.persistence.DBConnection    Opening DriverManager connection
2022/1/11 11:08:46.402  [TRACE] com.nuorbit.persistence.DBConnection    Opening DriverManager connection
2022/1/11 11:08:46.946  [ERROR] com.nuorbit.utils.Errors    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:283)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:278)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOsesskey(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:294)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:357)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.nuorbit.persistence.DBConnection.getConnectionByDriverManager(DBConnection.java:113)
    at com.nuorbit.persistence.DBConnection.getConnection(DBConnection.java:77)
    at com.nuorbit.persistence.DBConnection.getConnection(DBConnection.java:65)
    at com.nuorbit.utils.Settings.getSetting(Settings.java:116)
    at com.nuorbit.servlet.Startup.init(Startup.java:22)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1097)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:990)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4952)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5266)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I looked around for what might be causing that, and came across two common answers: replacing my ojdbc jar file, or changing the server's sqlnet.ora file by adding the following snipet:

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=10
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=10
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=10
```

Since the server is not under my control, I tried to do the former. I went into the build path, and replaced ojdbc14.jar with ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar. However, this still results in the same error, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image: ojdbc8.jar within the build path. Shouldn't this work?]

For reference, I am able to connect to the server using SQL Developer, as well as using Database Connection in the Data Source Explorer in Eclipse, so it seems like it's something wrong with my project specifically.

Let me know if there's anything I can clarify.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full text of the error message you're getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the old ojdbc was also in referenced libraries, so I needed to remove it from there to get it to work. Just replacing it on the build path wasn't enough.